# Using Wget to download an entire rss feed

Tags: linux, wordpress, drupal

Im trying to move a Drupal sites content http://www.philcooke.com/rss.xml using wget, but I am unable to download more then the 10 most recent stories. Ive set the rss feed in the Drupal admin to set rss feeds to show 30 items per feed. Ive done some searching, but I cant seem to find a way to have this display "all" and then use wget to download the posts.

If anyone knows of another way to download all of the posts (and comments for that matter) I wouldnt be opposed to trying that out as well, as at this point, Im willing to give any xml importing method a try. I should also mention the site runs Drupal 5.2 and Im trying to move it to Wordpress 3.0.1

Comment: I presume you've looked at the "advertised" [methods of migration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Drupal) on the wordpress codex?

Comment: Yes, I took a look at those scripts, but dont have full database access yet, only drupal un/pw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the views data source module to re-create a rss feed of any length - http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource

Comment: I ended up using this script http://blog.room34.com/archives/4530 but that looks like it could work. Maybe Ill give it a try this weekend, and report back here.